# ValueError: Length of object (1) does not match with length of fields (2)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am running Python script on Spark but I got the following error: ValueError: Length of object (1) does not match with length of fields (2). I will list down the code I am running and a screenshot for the error:

```
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("ApplySentimentModel")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)

# read the sentiment tsv file into an rdd and split it based upon tab
# the test file should be in the following format
# label->tab->tweet
lines = sc.textFile("test_file.tsv").map(lambda x: x.split("\t"))
# define the schema
schema = StructType([StructField("target", StringType(), True), StructField("tweet", StringType(), True)])
# create dataframe from rdd
docs = spark.createDataFrame(lines, schema)

# define the processing pipeline (tokenize->tf->idf->label_indexer)
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="tweet", outputCol="words")
hashtf = HashingTF(inputCol="words", outputCol='tf')
idf = IDF(inputCol='tf', outputCol="features", minDocFreq=5)
indexedLabel = StringIndexer(inputCol = "target", outputCol = "label")
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, hashtf, idf, indexedLabel])

# apply the pipeline to the testing datasets
pipelineFit = pipeline.fit(docs)
test_df = pipelineFit.transform(docs)

# load the trained model
lrModel = LogisticRegressionModel.load('lrModel.model')
# apply the model to predict the sentiment
predictions = lrModel.transform(test_df)

# compute the accuracy of predictions
accuracy = predictions.filter(predictions.label == predictions.prediction).count() / float(docs.count())
print("****************************************\n")
print("Prediction accuracy " + str(accuracy) + "\n")
print("****************************************\n")

# save the testing data, and the the target and predicted labels (0 -> positive, 1 -> negative)
predictions.select("tweet", "label", "prediction").write.format('csv').option('header',True).mode('overwrite').option('sep',',').save('predictions')

sc.stop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means your `lines` RDD only contain 1 column, but you asked for a dataframe with 2 columns to be created from the rdd. Check that your file contains two columns separated by a tab **on every line**. If some lines have missing entries, you will see the error you described.

Actually, if you want to create a dataframe from a tsv file, you're better off using

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("target", StringType(), True),
    StructField("tweet", StringType(), True)
])

docs = spark.read.csv('test_file.tsv', sep='\t', schema=schema)
```

which will take care of missing entries with NULL.